# Cookie, fetch, express, sessions are not persisting in Chrome

Tags: node.js, session, http-headers, fetch, session-cookies

I've read like a hundred of discussions on this topic. I had static html file and nodeJS server running locally. Now I run html file with live-server. I'm using fetch functions to check if the user authenticated. Here is the example:

```
const checkUser = async () => {
    const url = 'http://localhost:3000/user/check_user'

    try {
        const resp = await fetch(url, {
            method: 'GET',
            credentials: 'include',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        })

        if (resp.ok) {
            const json = await resp.json()
            return json
        } else {
            console.log("HTTP-Error: " + resp.status)
            return await resp.json()
        }

    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
    }
}
```

Here is example of server handling it:

```
router.get('/check_user', user_controller.check_user);

exports.check_user = async (req, res) => {
    // console.log(req.session)
    res.json({
        error: null,
        data: {
            message: "Check user",
            userID: req.session.userID ? req.session.userID : null
        },
    });
};
```

And here is the server config:

```
app.disable('x-powered-by');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

// sessions
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({
    // TODO: change secret
    secret: 'my-secret',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: MongoStore.create({
        mongoUrl: dev_db_url,
        // touchAfter: 12 * 3600 // twice a day
    }),
    cookie: {
        // TODO: change
        secure: true,
        sameSite: 'none',
        maxAge: 14 * 24 * 60 * 60 // 14 days
    }
}));
app.use(cors({
    origin: 'http://localhost:8080',
    methods: ['GET','POST'],
    credentials: true // enable set cookie
}));
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    // res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:8080");
    // res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
    // res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, authorization");
    // res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    // Example to check visits. Works in Firefox but not in Chrome
    try {
        req.session.visits = req.session.visits ? req.session.visits + 1 : 1;
        console.log('req.session.visits: ', req.session.visits);
        return next();
    } catch (err) {
        return next(err);
    }
});

// routes
app.use('/user', userRouter);

// This native get thing is working in Chrome
// app.get('/', function(req, res){
//     if(req.session.page_views){
//         req.session.page_views++;
//         res.send("You visited this page " + req.session.page_views + " times");
//     } else {
//         req.session.page_views = 1;
//         res.send("Welcome to this page for the first time!");
//     }
// });

let port = 3000;

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('The server is running on port number ' + port);
});
```

I've tried to set sameSite to true, disable and enable cors module, run live-server with and without cors flag, change order of app.use functions. If someone advised something, I'd appreciate it very much. Example is working in Firefox just fine, with user authentication as well. I don't want to launch chrome with some flags, every user should be able to use my app. How is it working for everyone else? Looks like I'm missing something important and very silly.

Without fetch with simple get to server it's working for Chrome as well. But I'd like to keep structure as it is (not to use get('/') and render functions)

Thanks and have a good day :)

Answer (score 0):

https://medium.com/swlh/how-the-new-chrome-80-cookie-rule-samesite-none-secure-affects-web-development-c06380220ced#2410 -- SSL and https for localhost or `sameSite: 'Lax'` should help